# Transforming a sum to an integral: why does it work?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, integration

The problem at hand has been discussed in loads of previous questions ([1](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/143467/), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/994722/), [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/624935/t))), and my version can be stated as follows.

Consider the sum $$\sum_{\mathbf k} \ln(1+e^{-(\alpha+\beta \varepsilon_k)}) \ .$$ We are summing over, say, two dimensional k-space lattice $\mathbf k = \frac{2\pi}{L}(n_x,n_y),$ where the $n_x,n_y$ run through the positive integers. **I want to understand *how* we can write this as an integral.** Our energy is given by $\varepsilon_k = \frac{\hbar^2 k^2}{2m}$.

Comment: -1. Not clear what you are asking. What is your question? How does it differ from those you have cited? "Is this a situation where hand-waving arguments are used in physics?" is a question teaching styles rather than the content of physics.  Why this procedure works is a question about mathematics rather than physics.

Comment: @sammygerbil My question is, indeed, why and how this procedure works. Since it is used extensively in statistical mechanics, I thought it would be on-topic at physics.stackexchange.

Comment: @sammygerbil I removed the phrase about hand-waving, to avoid distraction from my main problem.

Comment: Is your problem in the steps you show, or in the remaining steps until you get the energy integral?

Comment: @anonymous My problem is in the step where we subsitute a function $f(\mathbf k)$ in the sum $\sum_{\mathbf k} f(\mathbf k)$ and the assumptions made from here on to get the integral. I would be most satisfied if I could follow each (implicit) step made in this procedure. I've had (have been avoiding) this confusion for some time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Why does it work? By assuming the separation distance between the points in the discrete space is negligibly small compared to the total volume, we can make use of the *definition of the Riemann integral.***

---

Say we are summing over discrete points $\mathbf k$ in k-space $$\sum_\mathbf{k}\ f(\mathbf k)\ .$$

*If we want to rewrite this as an integral we have to assume that the
separation between the points in k-space $\Delta k$ is negligible in
comparison to the volume of the k-space $V$.*

In the following we can then use *the definition of the Riemann
integral*
\begin{align}
\sum_{\mathbf k} f(\mathbf k) &= \frac{1}{\Delta k} \sum_{\mathbf k}
f(\mathbf k) \Delta k \\
&\equiv \frac{1}{\Delta k}  \int_{\mbox{all space}} f(\mathbf k) d\mathbf k
\ ,
\end{align}
where, in the last step we used our assumption that our seperation
distance is negligibly small compared to the volume of the whole
space.